# An instance of mongoose.model is not instance of mongoose.Model?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mongoose

I am a bit confused by the inheritance structure of mongoose. This is a snippet of my code.

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
});

const MyName = new mongoose.model('MyName', MySchema);

const newNameEntry = new MyName({
  firstName: 'testFirstName',
  lastName: 'testLastName',
});

console.log(MySchema instanceof mongoose.Schema);
console.log(MyName instanceof mongoose.Model);
console.log(MyName instanceof mongoose.model);
console.log(MyName.prototype instanceof mongoose.Model);
console.log(MyName.prototype instanceof mongoose.model);

console.log(newNameEntry instanceof mongoose.Model);
```

So these are the result of the console log:

```
true
false
false
true
false
true
```

What I don't understand is why Myname is not an instance of mongoose.Model? What is the relationship between "Model" and "model"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like they messed up and their "Model" class is actually the "Entity" superclass that all instances inherit from. But it might have made sense at the time it was designed, `MyName` is a function that is usually not an instance of anything other than `Function`.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you very much for the reply. I am still learning javascript, but I thought the "new" keyword mean you are creating a new instance of an object/class, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to me why Myname is not an instanceof "model".

Do you mind also explain a bit the meaning of prototype in this context? Why the prototype of "MyName" is Model, but not model?

Comment: In general, yes, but the (constructor) function you call with `new` can in theory also return any other object (like a function object) that is not an instance, and js won't complain. From the docs it looks like `mongoos.model` is not meant to be used with `new` - it's a factory function that just returns an object that is not an instance of `model`.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Although what you said make sense. But this is from the official doc:

An instance of a model is called a document. Creating them and saving to the database is easy.

[link]https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

`const Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);`

`const small = new Tank({ size: 'small' });`
`small.save(function (err) {`
`  if (err) return handleError(err);`
 ` // saved!
`});`

Comment: Ah, right. Then forget that I said "Entity" above, it should be "the Document superclass". Basically `mongoose.model` will create a subclass of `Model`, which is the common ancestor class of all documents: `newNameEntry instanceof MyName` and `newNameEntry instanceof mongoose.Model`. `mongoose.model` is not a constructor, you shouldn't call it with `new` or use `instanceof` on it, although you won't get an exception.